# Wordpress in foreach loop updating meta values

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, meta-key

I have done foreach loop to get custom post type to frontend. And i have one custom field called 'order_staatus'. When i look in front end my list in loop, i want to add one button what would change this certain post 'order_staatus' to different value.. my code..

```
<? foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
   setup_postdata( $post );
?> 

<div class="profile_order_row">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_author(); ?> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
   <?php
      Global $post;
      if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
      {   
          if( ! isset( $post ) ) {
              echo 'Post not set';
              die();
          }
          else if( ! isset( $_POST['staatus'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['staatus'] ) ){
          echo 'Error';
          die();
          }

          $postid = $_POST['post_id'];
          update_post_meta($postid,'order_staatus','1');
      }

      $staatus = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'order_staatus', true);

      echo print_r($staatus);
   ?>

   <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="'.$post->ID.'" />
      <input type='text' name='staatus' value='<? echo $staatus ?>' />
      <input type='submit' value='save' />
   </form>

</div>


<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Where are you updating it? How are you updating it? AJAX? Where is the `update_post_meta` function?

Comment: This kind of logic should be placed in *functions.php* or a custom plugin...

Comment: Can you please give some directions or examples what im doing wrong? Or maybe someone knows some good plugin for it. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the issue is with the function `update_post_meta`.  I think the more likely issue is that `$_POST['submit']` is not set.  When submitting a form, the value of the submit button is not sent. The value attribute is simply for assigning the text of the button.

I would rewrite the IF block of code like this:

```
  if ( isset( $_POST ) )
    {   

      if( ! isset( $_POST['staatus'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['staatus'] ) ){
        echo 'Error';
        die();
      }

      $postid = sanitize_text_field($_POST['post_id']);
      update_post_meta($postid,'order_staatus','1');
  }
```

Note, that I removed the `isset($post)` check because you are running this code inside of  `foreach ( $postslist as $post )` which defines `$post` so it will always be set within that loop.

I also added the function `sanitize_text_field()` to sanitize the `post_id`.  This is an important security measure to avoid SQL injection.  All user input, including $_POST, can contain dangerous data and needs to be sanitized before use.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand and big thanks for your information! I guess there is issue with the function update_post_meta because, i thought it is wordpress function to change posts meta. Then i looked that "update_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value = '')" - it is correct wordpress function, is it possible to use this instead?

Comment: The difference is that update_post_meta is only for updating meta related to posts, while update_metadata can be used to update other types of meta data, like meta data related to comments and users.